If you experience problems with the browser web, do not use your smartphone
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':qr_code_scanner'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I have a namespace, but if I get an error like this, what should I do?
I wrote the namespace but the AGP menu is disabled.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Remove package element from manifest
package="com.your.unique.package.name"  from the <manifest> element in the AndroidManifest.xml file
Add build.gradle(:app) as namespace like this
android {
...
...
namespace 'your.package.name'
}

if your project multi-module do the same for all.
